# AppleScript Focus / Rename File (and clicking anywhere)

Tags: macos, workflow, applescript, automator, osx-leopard

```
on run {input}
    set filepath to POSIX path of input
    do shell script "touch " & quoted form of filepath & "untitled"
    return input
end run
```

Is what I have so far, and it works, but is there a way to then focus on the file then trigger a rename? I dont want the rename to be automatic, just trigger the event (like pressing "return" while you have a file selected). And I dont want to use any sort of modal...

**Quick Side question**: is there a way to set this so that i dont have to select a folder or file directly, but can do it by, lets say, clicking in a white space in a folder as long as it's in Finder? Right now I have my "Service receives selected" to "`files or folders`" in `Finder.app`.

== UPDATED CODE ==

```
on run {input}
    set filepath to POSIX path of input
    do shell script "touch " & quoted form of filepath & "untitled"
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        set target of Finder window 1 to POSIX file "/Users/oscargodson/Documents/designs/untitled"
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Finder"
            keystroke return
        end tell
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

If i hardcode the path it works! But how do I get it as a `var` that works?

Comment: What do you mean by focus?  You mean display in the Finder?

Comment: Like in web development, :focus. As if you clicked on a file one time and it marks it all blue whatever or if you navigate to a file with your arrow keys...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way. I think a modal window where you ask for the name would be better but you can try this. Notice you do not use "POSIX path" in this code. Applescript doesn't use POSIX paths. Also {input}, as indicated by the brackets around it, is a list of items. Therefore you act on the items of the list, and in this case we act on the first item.

```
set filepath to item 1 of input

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    reveal filepath
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

**EDIT: With your updated code, here's a working script...**

```
on run {input}
    if (class of input) is not list then set input to {input}
    set theFolder to (item 1 of input) as text

    try
        alias theFolder
        tell application "Finder"
            if (class of item theFolder) is not folder then error "input is not a folder."
            activate
            set theFile to make new file at folder theFolder with properties {name:"untitled"}
            reveal theFile
        end tell

        delay 0.2

        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Finder"
                keystroke return
            end tell
        end tell
    on error theError number errorNumber
        tell me
            activate
            display dialog "There was an error: " & (errorNumber as text) & return & return & theError buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with icon stop
            return
        end tell
    end try
    return input
end run
```

Comment: See my updated code. For whatever reason I can't figure out how to select the file. I tried your `set file path` thing, but i get an error each time I run it. I tried what Lri said below to select it (instead of Safari) but no luck either. also an error, but if i keep it set to safari it works. The keystroke return is perfect! Now, if you see my updated code, what do I do there to select that file?

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to set it up too so i can right click in the "white space" of a folder?

Comment: Crap, sorry for all the comments, but it looks like right click on a file (like how you would a folder) -> New File gives me an error popup?

Comment: "New File gives me an error popup?"... you mean in my code? I'm assuming you're passing a list of file alias's. OK, I added error checking to the code, so it should work or tell you the error.

Comment: So, whenever I right click on a file then do New File I get this: https://skitch.com/oscargodson/fbuek/finder

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    reopen -- in case there are no open windows
    set target of Finder window 1 to POSIX file "/Applications/Safari.app"
end tell
```

`reveal` and `select` always open a new window, `set target` and `set selection` don't.

I don't know why, but when `set selection` it used in column view, you can only select items in the entire contents of the target of the front window. The same thing doesn't happen in other views, so it seems like a bug.

---

Fix for the code in the edited question:

```
on go(input)
    set p to POSIX path of (input as text)
    set p2 to p & "untitled"
    do shell script "touch " & p2
    tell application "Finder"
        reopen
        activate
        set target of Finder window 1 to POSIX file p2
    end tell
    delay 0.3 -- time to release modifier keys
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
end go

tell application "Finder"
    set fold to folder (path to documents folder)
end tell
go(fold)
```

(That `on go` and the last lines are just for testing.)

Comment: Im super close... For the love of me i cant figure out how to select the FILE but i can select the Safari app. I want to select the file then `keystroke return`. I tried `set target of Finder window 1 to POSIX file filepath & "untitled"` but i get an error each time :(

Comment: Finder `folder`s and `file`s don't have a POSIX path property — you need to convert them to text or alias first. (As in `POSIX path of (<Finder folder> as text)`.) `quoted form of filepath & "untitled"` would need to be `quoted form of (filepath & "untitled")`.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an AppleScript based on the @regulus6633's one, but with some improvements.

**Note:** This answer was originally posted as an [AskDifferent answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/183269/124133). I'm copy/pasting here for convenience.

---

The idea is to create an Automator workflow and assigning a shortcut to it using the following steps:

- Open **Automator** and create a **Service**;
- Set the input to **no input**, and the application to **Finder.app**;
- Drag and Drop the **Run AppleScript** workflow element onto the grey space;
- Put the contents of this AppleScript in the textbox;
- Save the workflow with a reasonable name (like **New File**);
- Go to **Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services** and assign a shortcut to it.

Now, let's show the AppleScript:

```
set file_name to "untitled"
set file_ext to ".txt"
set is_desktop to false

-- get folder path and if we are in desktop (no folder opened)
try
    tell application "Finder"
        set this_folder to (folder of the front Finder window) as alias
    end tell
on error
    -- no open folder windows
    set this_folder to path to desktop folder as alias
    set is_desktop to true
end try

-- get the new file name (do not override an already existing file)
tell application "System Events"
    set file_list to get the name of every disk item of this_folder
end tell
set new_file to file_name & file_ext
set x to 1
repeat
    if new_file is in file_list then
        set new_file to file_name & " " & x & file_ext
        set x to x + 1
    else
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat

-- create and select the new file
tell application "Finder"

    activate
    set the_file to make new file at folder this_folder with properties {name:new_file}
    if is_desktop is false then
        reveal the_file
    else
        select window of desktop
        set selection to the_file
        delay 0.1
    end if
end tell

-- press enter (rename)
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

For convenience, I'm putting this AppleScript in [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/rarylson/5d20fc96335851365a02).